# Zero differential in Serre spectral sequence for configuration spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences, configuration-spaces

I moved this question from Math StackExchange.

I am trying to compute homology of $Conf(n, \mathbb{R}^2)$ - ordered configurations of $n$ points on the plane - using Serre spectral sequence. I know that this computations has been done for cohomology in Arnold's *The Cohomology Ring of Colored Braid Group*.

There is one step though which is unclear for me. Namely, he claims that $d_2$ - the only differential which might be non-zero - is actually zero.

> The only possible differential $d_2$ is in fact zero (this easily follows from the existence of the secant of the surface).

Why this is true?

Comment: What is secant of a surface?

Comment: I'm guessing, also by Neil's answer, that it might mean a section of the fibration.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'll write $C_n$ for the configuration space, and $X_n$ for $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $n$ points removed.  You are presumably thinking about the spectral sequence
$$ E_2^{pq} = H^p(C_{n-1};H^q(X_{n-1})) \Longrightarrow H^{p+q}(C_n), $$
with differentials $d_r\colon E_r^{pq}\to E_r^{p+r,q+1-r}$.  It is a key point that the projection $\pi\colon C_n\to C_{n-1}$ has a section: for example, we can use
$$ \sigma(z_1,\dotsc,z_{n-1}) = 
   \left(z_1,\dotsc,z_{n-1},(\max(\|z_1\|,\dotsc,\|z_{n-1}\|)+1).(1,0)\right).
$$
This implies that the map $\pi_1(C_n)\to\pi_1(C_{n-1})$ is surjective, and thus that $\pi_1(C_{n-1})$ acts trivially on $H^*(X_{n-1})$.  This is also a free abelian group by induction on $n$, so the $E_2$ term can be rewritten as $H^p(C_{n-1})\otimes H^q(X_{n-1})$.  It is clear that $H^*(X_{n-1})$ is generated by classes in degree $1$, and it will suffice to show that these support no differentials.  Any differentials after $d_2$ land in the lower half plane and so are zero.  The differential $d_2$ on $H^1(X_{n-1})$ lands in $H^2(C_{n-1})$, and anything in the image will be killed by the map $H^2(C_{n-1})\to H^2(C_n)$ (by the basic definition and properties of the Serre spectral sequence).  However, that map is injective, because of the existence of the section $\sigma$.  Thus, $d_2$ is zero and the spectral sequence collapses.

Comment: I know it's couple years later, but why surjectivity of the map $\pi_1(C_n)\to \pi_1(C_{n-1})$ implies that the action on the cohomology of the fiber is trivial?